# How to make a staggered nested loop using list comprehensions in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I have an array.

I want to output an array of arrays, where each inner array contains values that represent the numerical distance of each element to the elements after it.

So in better terms, I want to turn [1, 2, 3] into `[[1, 2], [1], []]`. If I was doing this in Javascript, it would be

```
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < thearray.length; i++){
     var innerArray = [];
     for (var j = i; j < thearray.length; j++){
          innerArray.push(Math.abs(thearray[j] - thearray[i]));
     }
     results.push(innerArray);
}
```

However, I am trying this with list comprehensions in Python, which I thought would be straightforward, but it is not working as I'd expect.

```
thearray = [1, 6, 8, 2]
[[abs(j-i) for j in thearray[i:]] for i in thearray]
# Result:   [[5, 7, 1], [], [], [6, 0]]
# Expecting [[5, 7, 1], [2, 4], [6], [0]]
```

Comment: swap the "for variable in" orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
[[abs(y-x) for y in thearray[idx+1:]] for idx, x in enumerate(thearray)]
```

Comment: Nice... I came up with something similar, but not quite as nice (I forget about enumerate - just not a lot of call for it in my work).  Note that the last element is empty, not [0], which is what I think should be expected.